# PHP/HTTP-API - how to call different PHP files from extern?

Tags: php, api, http

i am buildung a very simple PHP API, which answeros on HTTP requests. It should be able to create a user and delete one. So there are two PHP files/classes at the moment. One for deleting, one for creating/inserting a user.

My Question:

How do I need to call them (how does the URL look like) ? As i have seen at some examples, most people only call them via the path:

delete: `http://example.org/delete` or `http://example.org/delete.php`

create: `http://exmple.org/create` or `http://example.org/create.php`

So, do I have to create these paths ? Do i need to rename all my files to index.php and put them to the right path ?

I need to know, what an estabhlished praxis is (i work with php storm IDE).

Thank you.

Comment: Use the router for that.

Comment: sure - i mean, i get an error if i call it with the .php at the end - i do http requests out of java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approach for this are available...

**url rewriting**

in your .htaccess (if you don't have this file, then create it in your root folder) and copy this in :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Then call http://example.org/create, it will be re-written as http://example.org/index.php?page=create

If you want to keep two different pages (create.php and delete.php) so prefer this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

So, with this second variant http://example.org/create, will call http://example.org/create.php instead of index.php?page=create

**sub-folders**

I like this solution because it makes your API source code structured. So, create some subfolders with index.php in each one like this :

```
/_include
    -- config.php
    -- other scripts to include...
/create
    -- index.php
/delete
    -- index.php
```

So users will call http://example.org/create and http://example.org/delete ! You can make a _include folder with scripts called by both index.php.

Comment: okay, it is a bit confusing to have multiple index.php - but it seems to be legit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to point your URL to the location of your PHP file or the route. For example, if you point it to `http://example.com/delete` you need to make sure that a route for that exists.

Pointing your URL to `http://example.com/delete.php` would work fine as long as it exists.